# Does DocuSign provide REST API to integrate with our enterprise application

Tags: docusignapi

Can anybody please let me know if DocuSign provides access to its API(REST or otherwise) for consumption in our Enterprise Application. We have a project requirement for signing the documents via DocuSign using its API's support if any.
Need to understand if that is feasible or not.

Thanks in Advance!
Atul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, DocuSign has a publicly exposed REST API that allows you send and sign documents.

API Guides are available on the Developer Center: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides

as is the full API spec: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference